# Can't access Sails.js app instance in integration tests

Tags: testing, sails.js

I'm trying to write some integration tests in sailsjs.  I have a bootstrap.test.js file that lifts my server in a global before as the [docs suggest](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/Testing/Testing.md#bootstraptestjs).

In my integration test when I try to pass my sails app to supertest I get an error:

```
app is not defined
agent = request.agent(app.hooks.http.app);
                      ^
```

**bootstrap.test.js**

```
var Sails = require('sails'),
  Barrels = require('barrels'),
  app;

before(function(done) {
  console.log('Global before hook'); // Never called?
  this.timeout(5000);

  Sails.lift({

    log: {
      level: 'error'
    },
    models: {
      connection: 'test',
      migrate: 'drop'
    }
  }, function(err, sails) {
    app = sails;
    if (err) return done(err);

    var barrels = new Barrels();
    fixtures = barrels.data;

    barrels.populate(function(err) {
      done(err, sails);
    });
  });
});

// Global after hook
after(function (done) {
  console.log(); // Skip a line before displaying Sails lowering logs
  Sails.lower(done);
});
```

**integration test**

```
var chai = require('chai'),
  expect = chai.expect,
  request = require('supertest'),
  agent = request.agent(app.hooks.http.app);

describe('Species CRUD test', function() {

  it('should not allow an unauthenticated user create a species', function(done){
    var species = {
      scientificName: 'Latin name',
      commonName: 'Common name',
      taxon: 'Amphibian',
      leadOffice: 'Vero Beach',
      range: ['Florida', 'Georgia']
    };

    agent.post('species')
      .send(species)
      .end(function(err, species) {
        expect(err).to.exist;
        expect(species).to.not.exist;
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to make the integration test work for a few days now. This seems to be working fine in my environment. Maybe you can give it a try.

**bootstrap.test.js**

```
var Sails = require('sails');
var sails;

before(function(done)
{
  Sails.lift({
    log: {
        level: 'error'
      },
    connections: {
      testDB: {
        adapter: 'sails-memory'
      }
    },
    connection: 'testDB',
  }, function(err, server)
  {
    sails = server;
    if (err) return done(err);
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done)
{
  Sails.lower(done);
});
```

**Test**

```
 var request = require('supertest');
 it('should return all users', function(done){
   request(sails.hooks.http.app)
     .get('/user)
     .expect(200)
     .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
     .end(function(err, res){
        // check the response
        done();
     );
 }
```

I place bootstrap.test.js on the root of my test folder and then use mocha to run the test.

```
mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/**/*.test.js
```

Hope this help.

Comment: why does this work? doesn't `var sails` make scope the `sails` variable to `bootstrap.test.js`?  how is it available in the test file?  (I tried this and got `sails is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that since version 3.x of mocha, nodejs global variables capabilities was removed. so if you need it, you should specifically pass it to your environment like that:

```
mocha --globals global test/bootstrap.test.js test/**/*.test.js
```

or
in your mocha.opts file :

```
 #test/mocha.opts
 --globals global
```